# Storing an array of data using Redis (from Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have started to work with laravel. It is quite interesting to work. I have started to use the features of laravel. I have started to use `redis` by install redis server in my system and change the configuration for redis in `app/config/database.php` file. The redis is working fine for the single variables by using `set`. i.e.,

```
$redis = Redis::connection();

$redis->set('name', 'Test');
```

and i could able to get the value by using

```
$redis->get('name');
```

But i want to set the array by using `set` function. If i try do that getting the following error

```
 strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I have tried by using following codes.

```
$redis->set('name', array(5, 10));

$values = $redis->lrange('names', array(5, 10));
```

and if i use

```
$values = $redis->command('lrange', array(5, 10));
```

getting the following error

```
 'command' is not a registered Redis command
```

Can any one explain me the problem and is that possible with redis?...we can set the array values using `redis` ?

Comment: Redis isn't familiar with PHP non-scalar datatypes like arrays, but quick and dirty option would be `$redis->set('name', serialize(array(5, 10)));` or `$redis->set('name', json_encode(array(5, 10)));` and then unserialize or json_decode on get

Comment: So we have to encode it not other choice to set directly as an array?

Comment: A PHP array is a datatype specific to PHP, redis is language agnostic, so it has no idea how to handle it... personally I use Redis with igbinary and automatic serialization

Comment: @Kalai : you can store it as an associate-array without serializing, using laravel facade which i have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This has been answered in the comments but to make the answer clearer for people visiting in the future.

Redis is language agnostic so it won't recognise any datatype specific to PHP or any other language. The easiest way would be to `serialise` / `json_encode` the data on set then `unserialise`/`json_decode` on get.

Example to store data using `json_encode`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

$redis = Redis::connection();

$redis->set('user_details', json_encode([
        'first_name' => 'Alex', 
        'last_name' => 'Richards'
    ])
);
```

Example to retrieve data using `json_decode`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;

$redis    = Redis::connection();
$response = $redis->get('user_details');

$response = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Correct answer. MsgPack is also a good (language agnostic) encoding format. As a sidenote, this also applies to server-side Lua scripting. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287334/servicestack-redis-how-to-return-lua-table-as-list/22287807#22287807).

Comment: Are you aware how much time this will require until you decode and encode everything?

Comment: @DaAmidza This is like four years old now... there's probably a much more performant way to do this. Also, this answer made it as simple as possible for the OP (and others to understand)

Comment: @ajtrichards .. i tried but i am getting invalid arguments error . 127.0.0.1:6379>  set('user_details', json_encode(array('first_name' => 'Alex', 'last_name' => 'Richards')));
Invalid argument(s)

Comment: use Redis; at the top of file.

Answer (score 16):

Redis supports multiple data structure types like **hash**, **link list** and **array**.

But you have to use proper methods from **Laravel Redis facade** like below:

```php
// set user_details --redis_key-- and --redis_value-- as array of key_values 
Redis::hmset('user_details',["firstName" => "Foo", "lastName" => "Bar"]);

// get all as an associative array
Redis::hgetall('user_details');

// get just the keys as an array
Redis::hkeys('user_details');
```

Further information: https://redis.io/commands#hash

Answer (score -1):

In your controller, you can add such function:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
private function getUsers() {
    if ($users = Redis::get('users.all')) {
        return json_decode($users);
    }
    $users = User::all();
    Redis::set('users.all', $users);
    return $users;
}
```

Then in your `index` method (or others) you can do this:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $users = $this->getUsers();
}
```

Source: accepted answer and [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/store-collection-in-redis).